# 401 Invalid credentials when trying to reach the Google Search Console API in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, google-search-console

I'm trying to set up the Google Search Console API in Laravel and I'm struggling with getting it working with my newly-generated credentials. I've set up an API key in the console and inserted this into my code, however upon trying to fetch the data the application returns `401 Invalid credentials`. I feel really stupid for not being able to get this working since I would assume copying the API key and inserting it in my code would do the job. Which key is required to authenticate and retrieve data from the Search Console API?

I have tried setting up a new API key and using that key in the setAccessToken field. I even tried setting up Oauth 2.0 and using those credentials to authenticate. It seems the program crashes at 'setAccessToken'. The only other key I applied is the developer key (`$client->setDeveloperKey()`)

```
public static function debugSiteData() {
        // Dates (YYYY-mm-DD)
        $fromDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 months'));
        $toDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("application_name");
        $client->setDeveloperKey('AIza(...)');
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Webmasters::WEBMASTERS_READONLY);
        $webmaster = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);

        $searchConsole = new SearchConsoleClient($client);
        $searchConsole->setAccessToken("ACCESS TOKEN"); 
        // $debugData = var_export($searchConsole);

        $search = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
        $search->setStartDate($fromDate);
        $search->setEndDate($toDate);

        $console = $webmaster->urlcrawlerrorscounts->query('http://www.website.com/', array())->getCountPerTypes();

        return '<pre>' . $console . '</pre>';
    }
```

With the method above I'm getting a `401 Invalid credentials` error. I feel like it's something really simple but I can't seem to figure it out at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Oauth is a good idea to trigger Google APIs, in your case, you need to store the credentials in your DB after Oauth callback, `access_token`, `refresh_token`, `expires_in`, then you need to use those credentials to use the Google API's

```
$client = new Google_Client();

// Set Client Id (From Google Cloud Console)
$client->setClientId($client_id);

// Set Client Secret (From Google Cloud Console)
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);

// Set Access Token With Oauth credentials (form DB)
$client->setAccessToken([
      'access_token'  => $token, 
      'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
      'expires_in'    => $expires_in
]);

// Check if the access token is expired

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // This will refresh the token automatically
    $token = $client->refreshToken(null);
    $this->setAccessToken($token);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes a lot of sense, i'll definitely give this a shot.